# ¿Se pueden implementar funciones en socket.io?

Tags: socket.io

Tengo un incógnita por saber si se puede implementar funciones en socket.io Es para cambiar el color de un botón y que todos vean el cambio

```
const socket = io()

let btnColor = document.querySelector('#elector');

btnColor.addEventListener('click', function () { socket.emit('cambiar-color', btnColor.style.backgroundColor='#337ab7') });
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: soy Rodrigo y me estabas ayudando en mi pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/483955/243587